# When I right Click Desktop its Explorer Crash after i install Tortoise CVS. and also Tortoise CVS Icon is not showing

Tags: windows-7, cvs

I have install TortoiseCVS in software in My windows 7. After that if I right click on Desktop.  Explorer goes not responding. Restart the Explorer.

Whether the problem with TortoiseCVS. or windows 7.

Even the Repo Folder is not showing CVS Icon on it.

Comment: which version of Tortoise CVS are you using?

Comment: TortoiseCVS-1.8.32? does it have any problem?

Comment: Uninstall the older one and Make Sure you have uninstaled Tortoise CVS and also CVSNT 2.5. Restart your system. install this version.Tortoise CVS 1.12.5 .

Comment: Thanks it worked now. After restart installation of newer version. My explorer is not crushing now. I have problem I cant see the icons of CVS in repository folder. How should I do?

Comment: Add this Question in Main Question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its Icon Over relay Problem**

1. Go To Registry (Windows + R) Type `regedit`

**Make sure you take Backup of Registry before you modify in Reg edit. File - Export - Save it Location.**

2. Go To `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

This path You can see many like google drive, one drive, Skypepro, EnchancedStorageshell, offline files etc. Make sure Tortoise Icons are at top. Right Click and Delete other if its in top. Refer the below image.

[image]

3. Right Click on Desktop and Go To CVS -- Preferences.. -- Make sure you have Tick the `Autoload Folder Icon Overlays`. Refer Below Image. Restart your PC the Icon should come.

[image]